# Does the GPOI-Fan pin on the RPI 4 come defaulted on? and if so how do I disable it?

Tags: overlay, uart, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I have an RPI 4, and I need to use UART5. I have it enabled, and I am sending data to it, but it seems to be causing strange behaviour with the device connected to it. I ready that UART 5 conflicts with the GPIO-fan but I cant find out how to disable it if it is indeed defaulted to on.

Comment: Look for pin control configuration in the documentation or on internet sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen sites that indicate that the GPIO-Fan conflicts with USART5, But it seems the fan Ships defaulted off, so USART5 is good, and if you wish to enable the GPIO-fan you can set it to a different pin easily in the initialization eliminating the conflict between it and USART5.